# Chrome extension to paste clipboard content and search/go to the url

Tags: gratis, chrome, clipboard

It's hard to put a title for this, but is there a Google Chrome extension that gives me a context menu option to navigate to the url or search for the words in my clipboard.

By that I mean:

If my clipboard content was:

- `www.google.com` or maybe `http://www.google.com` then on clicking the context menu button, I would be taken to Google. But if it was
- `softwarerecs rules` then clicking on the context menu button would take me to a Google search of `softwarerecs rules`

Requirements:

- free
- Windows 7 chrome compatible
- context menu or maybe keyboard shortcut
- extension looks at the clipboard, detects whether it is a url or random words and does the appropriate action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep - it's called right click. On most OSs if you have something on the clipboard and click into the address bar then right click you will see options for "Paste" and "Paste & Search".

[image: Context Menu]

*Taken on Kubuntu 14.04*

You can also use standard keyboard shortcuts such as Control-V in the address bar.

- Free
- Most Platforms including windows XP..7 maybe even 8 & 10 *personally I never trust anything from MS with an even number - remember DOS4, Win2000,...*
- No download
- Both context menu and keyboard
- Minimal user intelligence needed to "do the right thing" - *actually if you paste anything but a URL Chrome will search providing you have a default search engine set*.

Comment: True. What I really was looking for was a context menu button I could press anywhere in the page so I could make an AHK script to it -to make it very quick to search or go to a search. Basically I wanted a single shortcut to search and navigate. +1 anyway :)

Comment: Wait never mind. I forgot about that last point on your answer - chrome already auto detects whether it's a url or not! So I could just AHK in the address bar, I think, and click paste, right?

Comment: Right! It does exactly that.

Comment: Wow. You know what - I don't think I deserve to have Chrome installed ;). Sorry for the really stupid question! I'll make the AHK script when I get back to my computer

Comment: You also don't actually have to copy text to the clipboard if it is on the current page - just select it and right click, or context menu, and if it is a URL you will have a "Go to ..." option and if not you will have "search google".  So no script needed.

Comment: True but I don't copy text from websites as often as I do other places, such as pdfs, text docs, etc... I do a lot of collaboration work with team members having some personal hatred against Google docs :)

Comment: Select the text in whatever windows you are working in, click or alt-tab to open web browser, Ctrl-L to select the address bar, Ctrl-V to paste into it, Enter to go.

Comment: Those shortcuts could be made into an AHK script as well - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use voice recognition software [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm) (Windows/Mac, non-free), you can create the voice command:

[image]

I use it daily, it's very convenient, especially with the Google Chrome extension [Auto Copy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-copy/bijpdibkloghppkbmhcklkogpjaenfkg) which automatically copies selected text to the clipboard.